# GridView RowUpdating can't get the new values,it gets only the old values

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i have this code:

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
    Dim strPersonID As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox).Text
    Dim s As String=e.NewValues[1].ToString()
    Dim strLastName As String = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox).Text
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("updatetest", cn)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", strPersonID)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pfirstname", strLastName)
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cn.Open()
    End If
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        cn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

the problem is that the event rowUpdating is returning the old values so how can i get the new values for the update? Notice that the programing is not running the event RowUpdated

any help?

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `RowUpdating` event is fired the changes have not yet been committed back to the datasource.  It's an event designed to give you an opportunity to validate the input and prevent the changes going forward if need be.

The [GridViewUpdateEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx) has two dictionaries in it, `OldValues` and `NewValues`.  You can figure out what's changed by looping over them like so:

```
For Each key As String In e.OldValues.Keys
    If e.OldValues(key) <> e.NewValues(key) Then
        MessageBox.Show(key & " has changed: Old Value = " & e.OldValues(key) & "; New Value = " & e.NewValues(key))
    End if
Next
```

That was brain compiler there, but I think the syntax is correct.