# Girdview data into parameter

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is going to be used to update a mysqldatabase, I only want to update 1 field,
It all works apart from getting the data from the input textbox on the gridview.
in the code below, strdocumentnumber = 77500 I want 77500 to come from the drawing No. column field of the updating row in the gridview and the value that i want to update is strAccess_Code also to come from the gridview Code column.
It all works if hard coding the values.

```
    Private Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
    '' do update..
    Dim strdocumentNumber As String = 77500
    Dim strAccess_Code As String = 8

    dbConn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;password=****;user id=root;database=drawlib;")
    sql = "UPDATE core " & vbCrLf & _
          "SET  F6 ='" & strAccess_Code & "'" & vbCrLf & _
           "WHERE F1 = '" & strdocumentNumber & "'"

    Try
        dbConn.Open()
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbConn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        dbread.Close()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error in Saving Data: " & myerror.Message)
        'dbread.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to create a textbox in your codebehind to assign a value from your gridview textbox:

*Edit*
You may need to find the proper row before pulling the value from the textbox.  Try this

```
Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)

If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
   Dim textbox As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("nameofyourgridview textbox here"),TextBox)
   strdocumentNumber = textbox.Text
End If
```

*/Edit*

In your Gridview, you'll need to change your BoundField to a TemplateField.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/05/27/tip-64-did-you-know-how-to-convert-a-gridview-column-from-asp-boundfield-to-asp-templatefield-in-design-view.aspx) for an example.

Use the designer to make the conversion (see link above) or select your column in the gridview designer and click the 'convert this column to a templatefield' button.  You'll then have a textbox that you can name and grab from the code-behind.

Comment: "nameofyourgridview textbox here" where dose this come from?

Comment: when I click the edit button the field in the code column becomes a textbox that I can edit, I then change the value then click the update button... this fires the gridview1_Rowupdating procedure. How can I get the new value entered to a textbox? I found this site but its for sql NOT Mysql and I dont have the knowledge to convert to my use.. http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-GridView-Update-Command-using-VB-Net.aspx

Comment: Ah, are you using boundfields in your gridview?  If so, you'll need to convert the column with the textbox value to be grabbed to a templatefield.  I'll update my example above with a snippet.

Comment: You may also be running into an oldvalues vs newvalues issue in the rowupdating event.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328748/gridview-rowupdating-cant-get-the-new-values-it-gets-only-the-old-values for an explanation, but you may need to iterate the new values collection to grab the new value from your textbox.

Comment: Thanks, your help so far, has been great.

Comment: HI I still cant get this to work, can't see why its being so hard to do?? Iv chaged the boundfield to a template field and changed the textbox name to DoNumBox1. now in the WHERE of the sql statment, strdocumentNumber is showing a warning: Variable strdocumentNumber is used before it has been assigned a value. So I take this to mean that strdocumentNumber is not getting the value of the textbox "DocNumBox1"

Comment: Got it :) changed 'Dim textbox As TextBox = CType(row.FindControl("CodeBox1"),TextBox)'  to  'Dim textbox As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("CodeBox1"), TextBox)'